# How can i get NameValuePair data from post url in c#(MVC)

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc

I am sending HttpPost request from android device by adding NameValuePair but not getting how to fetch the NameValuePair values in Controller.

Here is the code for sending request:-

```
HttpPost request=new HttpPost(PostUrl);
HttpResponse response;
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName",userName));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",Password));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId",deviceId));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subdomain",Subdomain));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceType",DeviceType));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uniqueId",UniqueId));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("appVersion",AppVersion));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
    response = client.execute(request);
```

this is the NameValuePair i am sending ..

Now Here is the code(C#) of my Account Controller and Method login where i am posting these data.

```
public LoginResponse login( NameValueCollection post, String UserName, String password, String deviceId, String subdomain, String deviceType,String uniqueId,String appVersion)
{
String User=Convert.toString(post["userName"]);


}
```

Please tell me how should i get the NameValuePair in this method .if i send all parameters by appending to Post Url then its working fine but if i am sending it through NameValuePair then the value of **User** is always null

Comment: Can you please give further insight what the value of the post object is during the runtime?
Is it also null or a valid NameValuePair List ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public LoginResponse login(NameValueCollection post)
{
    string test1 = post.Get("userName");
    string test2 = post.Get("password");
}
```

Also, if this is MVC pick a standard result (in this case, ContentResult returns a string):

```
public ContentResult login(NameValueCollection post)
{
    LoginResponse loginResponse = //some method call...

    return Content("login", loginResponse)
}
```

Let me know if it works. If not I have a couple of other suggestions for you.

Comment: Use browser development tools to inspect network communication. Verify in request that names and values are posting correctly. Also, you do have [HttpPost] attribute on your action method, right?

Comment: I Use this and this is working for me.
     HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
     string user_Name = current.Request.Params["userName"];